# javascript created table has rows that do stretch to table width

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I dynamically create a table in javascript and append it to a div.  The resulting table seems to have all the same tags and stylings as a straight up html table I used in the proof of concept, yet the table cells do not stretch.

When I place a border on the table, I see that the table itself is at 100% width, but the outlined cells simply do not stretch to fill it out (it looks like a table inside another one cell table in Chrome).

Both IE and Chrome give me the same behavior.

Here is my code:

```
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");  
    tbl.cellPadding = 0; tbl.cellSpacing = 0; 
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tblBody"); 
    var tr = document.createElement("tr"); 
    var td;

    td = document.createElement("td"); 
    td.style.width="70px"; 
    td.appendChild(this.getFirstDiv());
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("td"); 
    td.style.width="300px"; 
    td.appendChild(this.getSecondDiv());
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.appendChild(this.getThirdDiv());
    tr.appendChild(td);

    tblBody.appendChild(tr); 
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious here.  I have tried display attributes for table and table-row.  I have tried width: auto.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no such thing as `tblBody`. Replace it by `tbody`.

Comment: You could provide a `jsfiddle` for the problem

Comment: wow - thanks - I hate those obvious ones.